# Rate, Priority, and Percentage

Tags: percentages, ratio

I am not sure how to properly title the question. I will describe it.

I have a total of 100 seats at a venue. I have two gates to the venue, gate A, and B.

Arbitrarily I want to have 30% of the attendees pass through gate A, and the other 70% enter via gate B.

I take a look at the people who entered I find that 50 people entered out of 100. 40% currently passed through gate A, and 60% passed through gate B.

What would be the formula to find out what percentage of the people I need pass through gate A, and gate B to get close to the 30% gate A, and 70% gate B ratio.

Merci!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merci beaucoup, and let's work out how many people passed through A and B respectively: $50×40\%=20$ and $50×60\%=30$ respectively.

This leaves 10 and 40 people left to go through to reach the desired ratio. So of the remainder, you need 20% to go through A and 80% through B.

Comment: Could I expand the question to say my venue has infinite seats? Is there a way to still find out the percentages?

Comment: @MontrealDevOne If your venue has infinite seats, no matter how many _finite_ number of people entered, you would have to admit infinitely many people in the same proportion as your intended distribution of entering gates in the end. That question, at least, makes no sense...

Comment: I guess the seat analogy might not work. However in the case of routing traffic on a road etc, if I have two gates on a bridge and  40% of the traffic pass via gate A, and the other 60% via gate B. What percentages do I need to work out to 30% gate A and 70% gate B.

Comment: @MontrealDevOne It remains the same then as with my answer. After getting the number of cars passed through each gate, subtract from your intended number of vehicles for each gate, then convert to percentages.